# How can I display data from MYSQL database using HTML table from a PHP file?

Tags: php, html, css

Using the PHP code below I get two separate tables for each row in MYSQL database table. How can I get the code to display the data in one table? Also for some reason the CSS is not getting applied to some parts of the PHP file where I have links to edit and remove data, and the background color of the table row. Should I apply the CSS directly in the PHP file? or is there any other way to do it?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
    $initials=parse_ini_file("../.ht.asetukset.ini");
    try {
        $connection=mysqli_connect($initials["databaseserver"], 
                                   $initials["username"],
                                   $initials["password"],
                                   $initials["database"]
                                   );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        header("Location:../html/yhteysvirhe.html");
        exit;
    }
?>
<?php
    include "../html/admin_header.html";
?>
 <?php
 //getting result from database
 $print=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($print)) {
 echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>First Name</th>";
    echo "<th>last Name</th>";
    echo "<th>User Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Password</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
    echo "<th>Delete</th>";
    echo "<th>Edit</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->fname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->lname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->uname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->email</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->paswd</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->descrip</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2><a style='color:white' href='./admin_remove.php?poistettava=$row->id'>Delete</a></h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2<a href='./admin_edit.php?editable=$row->id'>Edit</a></h2></td>";
 }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>

<?php
    include "../html/admin_footer.html";
?>
```

This is the result I get:

```css
/*body background color.*/

body {
  background-color: #2f303a;
}


/*Removing underline from hyper
links.*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1d19f6;
}


/*navbar bakground color change.
*/

.navbar {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}


/* Spaces between items are increased
in the navbar.*/

.navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 40px;
}


/* Spaces between items are increased
in the navbar.*/

.nav-item {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}


/**/

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #eeea14;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #00ff6a;
}


/* Search bar with rounded corners
and white & blue background.*/

.navbar1 {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}


/* Search bar with rounded corners
and white & blue background.*/

.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
}


/* Search bar with rounded corners
and white & blue background.*/

.form-control1 {
  color: #555555;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 299px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}


/*box config.*/

.box {
  background-color: #ffffffea;
  width: auto;
  height: 556px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*can be used to add spacing between 
items stacked on top of each other.*/

.padding {
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}


/*container.*/

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: static;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.sec {
  background-color: #ffffffea;
  width: auto;
  height: 556px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #2f303a;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sec1 {
  padding-top: 1%;
  background-color: #ffffffea;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #2f303a;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*white boxes config.*/

.box1 {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1d19f6;
  width: 358px;
  height: 293px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #494848;
}

.box2 {
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}


/*footer config*/

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #2f303a;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="Team 14 project work. The website contains basic web development guides utilizing HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and Bootstrap">
  <title>admin</title>
  <!--Link to bootstrap.-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
  <!--Link to local css file.-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!--navigation bar starts here.-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="color: #0000ff; font-family:'Dosis', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;"><b>CodeSchool</b></a>
        <div id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="./html.html">HTML Basics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="./css.html">CSS Basics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="./js.html">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--anchor link added.-->
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#a">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--anchor link added.-->
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#b">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--anchor link added.-->
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Log In / Sgin Up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--navigation bar ends here.-->
  <main>
    <!--box with search bar starts here.-->
    <div class="box">
      <h1 class="padding"><b>Welcome to the Admin Page</b></h1><br>
      <h1 class="padding"><b>Here you can edit users' data and/or remove profiles from the database</b></h1><br>
    </div>
    <!--box with search bar ends here.-->
    <!--other content.-->
    <div class="sec1">
      <h1 class="padding"><b>Users list:</b></h1><br>
    </div>
    <div class="sec">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>last Name</th>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Password</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h2>1</h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>Admin</h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>Admin</h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>admin</h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2></h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>password</h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>Adiminstrator</h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2><a style='color:white' href='./admin_remove.php?poistettava=1'>Delete</a></h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2<a href='./admin_edit.php?editable=1'>Edit</a>
                </h2>
            </td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>last Name</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <h2>2</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2>test</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2>test</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2>tester</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2>test@test.test</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2>test</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2>testing</h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2><a style='color:white' href='./admin_remove.php?poistettava=2'>Delete</a></h2>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <h2<a href='./admin_edit.php?editable=2'>Edit</a>
                      </h2>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="a">
      <h1><b>About Us</b></h1>
      <h3>We are a group of students dedicated to sharing our knowledge as we progress with our studies.</h3>
    </div>
    <!--content ends here.-->
  </main>
  <!--Footer starts here.-->

  <footer>
    <section class="mb-4" id="b">
      <!--Section heading-->
      <h2 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4">Contact Us</h2>
      <!--Section description-->
      <p class="text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">Do you have any questions? Please do not hesitate to contact us directly. Our team will come back to you within a matter of hours to help you.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5">
          <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                  <label for="name" class="">Your name</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                  <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
                  <label for="subject" class="">Subject</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="md-form">
                  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
                  <label for="message">Your message</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
          <div class="text-center text-md-left">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();">Send</a>
          </div>
          <div class="status"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
            <li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i>
              <p>Visamäentie 35 A, 13100 Hämeenlinna</p>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-phone mt-4 fa-2x"></i>
              <p>(+358) 23456 789</p>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-envelope mt-4 fa-2x"></i>
              <p>email@email.com</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="py-3 my-4">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Instagram</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">LinkedIn</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Discord</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="text-center text-muted">&copy; 2022 HAMK, Team 14</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!--Footer ends here.-->
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just a note: The use of `?> <?php` accomplishes nothing. You can leave it out.

Comment: _"How can I get the code to display the data in one table?"_ - by not creating opening and closing `table` tags _inside_ the loop, but before/after it ...?

Comment: You should move all the `<th>...</th>`' (including the `<tr>` around them) to before the loop as well.

Comment: `<h2<a href` h2 is not closed here, could be a cause for styles not getting applied

Comment: Thank you guys that helped a lot. I am quite a beginner and I  understand that my question appear to be dumb. but thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping the table tag in while loop that's why multiple tables are getting created. Try doing like this

```js
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>First Name</th>";
    echo "<th>last Name</th>";
    echo "<th>User Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Password</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
    echo "<th>Delete</th>";
    echo "<th>Edit</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($print)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->fname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->lname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->uname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->email</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->paswd</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->descrip</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2><a style='color:white' href='./admin_remove.php?poistettava=$row->id'>Delete</a></h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2<a href='./admin_edit.php?editable=$row->id'>Edit</a></h2></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
    
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much of it will be solved,

but I would start by taking the `<table>` tag and the first row of `<th>` tags outside of the while loop (just like your closing `</table>` is outside of the loop):

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>First Name</th>";
echo "<th>last Name</th>";
echo "<th>User Name</th>";
echo "<th>Email</th>";
echo "<th>Password</th>";
echo "<th>Description</th>";
echo "<th>Delete</th>";
echo "<th>Edit</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($print)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->id</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->fname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->lname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->uname</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->email</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->paswd</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>$row->descrip</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2><a style='color:white' href='./admin_remove.php?poistettava=$row->id'>Delete</a></h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2<a href='./admin_edit.php?editable=$row->id'>Edit</a></h2></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```